# Pass javascript value to C# value

Tags: javascript, c#

I use ASP.NET MVC.And I want to pass Javascript value to C# value.For example:
C# Code:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
string value;
}
```

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tbody tr").click(function () {
            if (typeof $obj != 'undefined') {
                $obj.css("background-color", "white");
            }
            $obj = $(this);
            $obj.css("background", "#ADDEFF");
            @value = this.attr("class").toString();
        }
    );
```

I need to assign a value

Comment: You can't assign a value to a server side c# variable using javascript in the browser. Why do you thinkm you need to do this, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between **client-side** code and **server-side** code.

Comment: You need to understand the flow of each one... When your javascript is executed, the server-side code (C#) is gone... They are not running at the same time

Comment: You must use AJAX to do that.why you want to pass Javascript value to C# value ?

Answer (score 3):

C# is server-sided, Javascript is client-sided. There is no way to pass values to c# from Javascript, as all C# code is parsed before your Javascript code is being called. You could try implementing hidden fields and populate them using Ajax, but I wouldn't recommend it. More information about this can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/708697/Pass-javascript-variables-value-to-Csharp-code-beh

Here are the differences between client-side scripting and server-side scripting, copied from [here](http://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/ClientSide01CD/page_18.htm):

**Client-side Environment**

> The client-side environment used to run scripts is usually a browser.
>   The processing takes place on the end users computer. The source code
>   is transferred from the web server to the users computer over the
>   internet and run directly in the browser.
>
> The scripting language needs to be enabled on the client computer.
>   Sometimes if a user is conscious of security risks they may switch the
>   scripting facility off. When this is the case a message usually pops
>   up to alert the user when script is attempting to run.

**Server-side Environment**

> The server-side environment that runs a scripting language is a web
>   server. A user's request is fulfilled by running a script directly on
>   the web server to generate dynamic HTML pages. This HTML is then sent
>   to the client browser. It is usually used to provide interactive web
>   sites that interface to databases or other data stores on the server.
>
> This is different from client-side scripting where scripts are run by
>   the viewing web browser, usually in JavaScript. The primary advantage
>   to server-side scripting is the ability to highly customize the
>   response based on the user's requirements, access rights, or queries
>   into data stores.